# How to select a Substring from a string in c# efficiently

Tags: c#

I am trying to select specific string "`Compression:` " value which is `Deflate` in this case.

below is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" + 
        "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " + 
        "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      ...";

    string s1 = info.Substring((info.IndexOf("Compression:")), 
        info.Length - info.IndexOf("Compression:") - 1);

    var replace = s1.Replace("Compression: ", "");
}
```

here, i am getting all the string having substring "`Compression`"

is there a efficient way to get only `Deflate` of `Compression` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Split the string on carriage returns, then split each element on colon?

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Actually split on newlines since the OP has `\n` in the string not `\r`.

Comment: @mjwills Currently,I am getting response like this: 
`replace = "Deflate\n        Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      .."`
I just want `Deflate`string.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string on the `\n` character to get an array of name-value pairs, then find the one that starts with your search string (`"Compression"`), then split that on the `:` character and return the second part.

To generalize it, you could write a function that takes in your search string and the string to search, which returns the value for the specified name if found (or `null` if not found):

```
public static string GetValue(string name, string source)
{
    if (source == null || name == null) return null;

    var result = source.Split('\n')
        .Select(i => i.Trim())
        .FirstOrDefault(i => i.StartsWith(name + ":", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        ?.Split(':');

    return result?.Length == 2 ? result[1].Trim() : null;
}
```

Then you could call this with different "names" to find their values:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" +
                "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " +
                "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      ...";

    var compression = GetValue("Compression", info);
    var zipEntry = GetValue("ZipEntry", info);

    Console.WriteLine($"Compression = {compression}, ZipEntry = {zipEntry}");

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Alternatively, you could write the method so it returns **ALL** the key/value pairs from the string in the form of a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Then you can lookup values by name:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetNameValuePairs(string source)
{
    return source?.Split('\n')
        .Select(i => i.Split(':'))
        .ToDictionary(k => k[0].Trim(), v => v.Length > 1 ? v[1].Trim() : null,
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" +
                "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " +
                "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      ...";

    var keyValuePairs = GetKeyValuePairs(info);

    // Write out all the name/value pairs found
    foreach (var kvp in keyValuePairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} = {kvp.Value}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

> is there a efficient way to get only Deflate of Compression ?

You could use the `Span<T>`/`ReadOnlySpan<char>` type that was introduced in .NET Core 2.1 and the [System.Memory NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" +
            "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " +
            "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      ...";

    ReadOnlySpan<char> span = info.AsSpan();
    ReadOnlySpan<char> compression = "Compression: ".AsSpan();
    int startIndex = span.IndexOf(compression);
    if (startIndex != -1)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<char> deflate = span.Slice(startIndex + compression.Length);
        int endIndex = deflate.IndexOf('\n');
        if (endIndex != -1)
        {
            string s1 = deflate.Slice(0, endIndex).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

It saves you from having to allocate necessary substrings and allocated memory in vain. Please refer to [Stephen Toub's MSDN Magazine article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your leading and trailing space are useless, here is way you can do it with [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) and `linq`. Explanations are in code comment.

```
var compressionValue = info
     // Process data per line 
    .Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     // Remove leading and trailing space
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    // Check for "Compression" header
    .Where(r => r.StartsWith("Compression: "))
    // Get corresponding value
    .Select(s => s.Substring("Compression: ".Length))
    // Select the first Match, null if "Compression : " is not found
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can as well work with cutting your string into pieces using Substring().

But it's most easily possible using a regular expression:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" + 
        "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " + 
        "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      ...";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(info, @"(?<=Compression: )([^\\n]*)");

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"- Match: {match.Value}");
    }
}
```

The regular expression uses a `lookaround` (specifically a `lookbehind` in this case) clause to check for a string that is preceeded by "Compression: ". It then starts capturing any character that is not `\n` (which has to be double escaped). Everything else is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it's going to be \n after the value "Deflate", you can do this:

```
if(s1.Contains('\n'))
{
     s1 = s1.Split('\n')[0];
}
var replace = s1.Replace("Compression: ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" +
        "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " +
        "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n  ";
    List<string> splittedinfo = info.Split('\n');
    foreach (string s in splittedinfo)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()))
        {
            var ss = s.Split(':');
            if (ss[0].Trim() == "Compression")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ss[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string key = "Compressed",  endstring = "\n";
    char separator = ':';
    var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n" +
        "         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        " +
        "Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n  ";

    info = info.Substring(info.IndexOf(key));
    info = info.Substring(0, info.IndexOf(endstring));
    info = info.Split(separator)[1].Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(info);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the string into a dictionary, so that you can access any desired value easily:

```
        var info = "ZipEntry: testfile.txt\n   Version Made By: 45\n Needed to extract: 45\n         File type: binary\n       Compression: Deflate\n        Compressed: 0x35556371\n      Uncompressed: 0x1D626FBDB\n      ...";

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        IList<string> split = info.Split(new char[] { ':', '\n' }).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();

        if (split.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < split.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 != 0)
                    values.Add(split[i - 1], split[i]);
                else if (i == split.Count - 1)
                    values.Add(split[i], "");
            }
        }

        string compression = values["Compression"];
```